# Xubuntu software update failed

Tags: xubuntu

I tried to make update on my system (4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:37:27 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux ) via software updater but the update failed. So I tried to make the update via apt-get command but also not successfully. There was this output:

`Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Get:1 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk all 1:18.04.24 [9 360 B] Get:2 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:18.04.24 [24,3 kB] Get:3 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 python3-distupgrade all 1:18.04.24 [105 kB] Fetched 139 kB in 0s (881 kB/s)
Extracting templates from packages: 100% Preconfiguring packages ... Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ... /usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure): installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing: install-info`

What was wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Please post your terminal session as a code block, and describe what “failed” means.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include the command you've executed? Also give the contents of your /etc/environment file using `cat  /etc/environment`

Comment: From the output we understand that there is Syntax error in the file /etc/environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check, if you have all needed folders in enviroment PATH like this:

```
# sudo echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

If not, you need correct this through adding appropriate folders to PATH variable.

Additionally check syntax at this file:

```
# sudo nano /etc/environment
```

All missing a `"` must be there.

Comment: Thank you, there was missing quotes in JAVA_HOME path in /etc/environment file.